# Ajax submission leads to => An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (2 MB) that this server supports

Tags: forms, ajax

So i'm trying to submit a form using ajax, in my form i have the following:

```
        $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
        $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('OK'),
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
        '#prefix' => '<div class="tc btn_pay relative">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>
                        </div>',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('proximabold', 'tc', 'transition', 'no-underline', 'ph3', 'pv2', 'mb2', 'dib', 'white'),
        ),
        '#ajax' => [
            'event' => 'click',
            'callback' => '::updateTable',
            'wrapper' => 'table-wrapper',
            'progress' => [
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => t('Verifying entry...'),
            ],
        ],
    );
```

and a simple updateTable function:

```
public function updateTable(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

But when i click on submit i get the error:
**An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (2 MB) that this server supports.**

I knew that the error is server side (Maybe i'm wrong), so i went to php.ini (i use PHP7) and update the following lines:

```
post_max_size = 6144M
memory_limit = 6144M
upload_max_filesize = 6144M
max_file_uploads = 1000
```

but without luck, this configuration shouldn't be necessary as the request size is only 1.5KB

Comment: i found that the mod_security module create some obstacles for ajax submission but i don't even have the latter installed!!

Answer (score 9):

By debugging the code I found the solution. The error was triggered from `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/EventSubscriber/FormAjaxSubscriber.php`

```
if ($exception instanceof BrokenPostRequestException && $request->query->has(FormBuilderInterface::AJAX_FORM_REQUEST)) {
  $this->drupalSetMessage($this->t('An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (@size) that this server supports.', ['@size' => $this->formatSize($exception->getSize())]), 'error');
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $status_messages = ['#type' => 'status_messages'];
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand(NULL, $status_messages));
  $response->headers->set('X-Status-Code', 200);
  $event->setResponse($response);
  return;
}
```

The error triggered if the `BrokenPostRequestException` exception is thrown.

Now if we got to `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php` we find that this exception is thrown if the post request is bigger than what is allowed by the server and also if the **request doesn't carry the form id**.

```
if ($ajax_form_request && !$request->request->has('form_id')) {
  throw new BrokenPostRequestException($this->getFileUploadMaxSize());
}
```

> It would be better if there was another exception for this case
> rather than getting the same error for when the post request exceeds
> the configured allowed size (post_max_size)

In my case it was not a matter of post size request, rather I didn't include the form id in my twig file.

I added the lines containing *form_id* and *form_build_id*:

```
<div class="fr relative filtrehold">
        <div class="filtr_btn  br-pill shadow-2 ttu dark-gray f5 proximabold">Filtres</div>
        <form> //Added this one
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.form_build_id }} // Added
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.form_id }} // Added 
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.RelevesMensuels }}
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.from }}
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.to }}
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.example_select }}
            {{ McRefund_build_data.filterform.actions.submit }}
        </form> //Added this one
</div>
<div class="table_hold bg-white br2">

    <div id="table-wrapper">

        {% for Num_refund,refund in McRefund_build_data.filterform.RefundsContainer['Refunds']['#Refunds_data'] %}
                   ............
                   ............
                   ............
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Just ran in to this. Thank you!

Comment: My problem: I was adding a 'destination' parameter to the url of the ajax link that opened my custom form, and used the destination in my submit handler, to issue a form redirect, causing the redirect to appear to be an ajax request in /Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php:299, but without the form_id (since it was in fact a GET (redirect)), and thus exploded with that misleading upload file size error.

My solution: Remove the destination parameter from the ajax link, so as not to confuse the ajax handling of the form builder on the redirect; and handle the redirect a different way.

Comment: Great job @SteveOliver, glad it helped :D

Comment: FYI: on my side, it was the opposite=> My themed form was containing the `<form...>` tag. But as it was inside an inline entity form I got this problem. Removing this tag solved it.

Comment: This is super help.. add form_id, form_build_id  to your twig file solved my problem. Many many thanks to you

Answer (score 5):

Due to an identical error message ("***An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size that this server supports***")in a project based on Drupal 8, I just discovered a third use of the same exception discussed above.
In my case, the exception was thrown by reaching limit of allowed variables in the php.ini file.

1. **Open the file** -> vim /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
2. **Locate the line** -> /max_input_vars/n
3. **Uncomment the line and put** -> max_input_vars = 3000
4. **Restart Apache** -> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

[image: max_input_vars in php.ini]

My two Cents.

Comment: Thank you! I was running into this error on a Webform with 300 options. Increasing `max_input_vars` fixed the error for me. I'm also on Acquia so I had to increase it via the Acquia dashboard as described here: https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005840813-Website-exceeds-PHP-s-max-input-vars