# Debugging Ajax Callback

Tags: 8, ajax, debugging

Goal: Print/dump `$formState` values to debug

I am altering a form and the functionality works:

```
$form['elements']['location']['deparment']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'myAjaxCallback',
  'event' => 'change',
  'progress' => [
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => t('Verifying entry...'),
  ]
];
```

but what I want is to be able to print out `$formState` in myAjaxCallback

```
function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState){
 $response = new AjaxResponse();
 print_r($formState); //I've tried, with memory_limit=-1 . it just hangs
 dump($formState); //gives me File upload exceeds. This comes from issue with using dump in ajax
                     https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250078/ajax-submission-leads-to-an-unrecoverable-error-occurred-the-uploaded-file-l

 return $response
}
```

I have also read https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/ajax-forms and tried their Debugging AJAX Callback Functions, which has:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$debugOut = @Kint::dump($formState); //but this uses dump too, which gives me ajax errors
```

so `dd($formState->getValues());` kind of works. This is what it shows me. So, as you can see, I can now see the variables. It's not the best, but readable.

[image]

whereas if I go to [website]/webform?ajax_form=1 , it's not even readable.

[image]

I am running out of ideas to be able to debug the variable `$formState` .

Comment: Have you tried using [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)?

Comment: @sonfd I have not. I'll give it a go

Comment: @sonfd can you submit your comment as the solution. Just installed [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/wizard) for phpstorm on XAMP, it's amazing! exactly what I've always needed!

Comment: Armando Silva - go ahead and add it as an answer and feel free to add any helpful details you can about setting it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sonfd [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) helps print out the values beautifully. No more print_r() or kint() errors.

[image]